# Impact of unlabelled instances in model construction (Neural network) in Weka

Tags: neural-network, classification, weka, missing-data

Two situations:

1. I have a set of instances with label "0", "1", and "?". I use the labelled ones (1,0) to train a multilayer perceptron (default settings, SMOTE correction, LOOCV to estimate performance), build a model and then predict the "?" instances.
2. I use all instances (1, 0, ?) to train the NN (default settings, SMOTE correction for imbalance between 1 and 0 instances, as before, and LOOCV to estimate performance).

Scores given to each prediction change between both situations.

My question is, how does NN handle having unlabelled instances in the training set? Is situation 1 a bad approach?

thanks